# What to call light food served at cocktail parties, that can be eaten on the thumb?

Tags: word-request, image-identification, food

At receptions, small pieces of food are often served, that can be eaten "on the thumb" even when holding a cup of champagne in the other hand.

What to call this kind of food in English?

I was convinced this could be called "thumb food", but [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q="thumb+food") [proves me](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22thumb%20food%22%20-tom) [wrong](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22thumb%20food%22%20-tom%20-%22Good%20Thumb%20Food%20Centre%22).

[image]

Comment: In the UK and often in slightly less formal situations these are called 'Nibbles'. (A nibble is a tiny bite).

Comment: @Tristan: In *even less formal* situations, they might be called [snacky-poos](http://www.foodie.com/collections/katie-brescia/snacky-poos) by the "twee" middle class, or [munchies](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=pictures+munchies&rlz=1C2CHFX_en-GBGB569GB569&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=P1ygU6qJE-Wp7AaD7ICgDg&ved=0CCsQ7Ak&biw=1144&bih=853) by the sugar/fat-obsessed proles.

Comment: In my circle, we just call them "bites" to mean "finger food" served at cocktails or parties

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[**Finger food**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finger_food) comes to mind.  You were close with your thumb!

They are also conventionally called *appetizers* or *hors d'oeuvres*, even though according to the strict definitions *appetizers* or *hors d'oeuvres* precede proper meals, whereas at cocktail parties, an actual meal does not normally follow.

Comment: "Finger food" answers the question but is a little informal.

Comment: Strict definitions aside, an appetizer is widely understood to precede a meal, which doesn't apply to hors d'oeuvres.

Comment: Growing up in California and living in Massachusetts, either "finger food" or "hors d'oeuvres" would be understood to indicate the OP's picture. "Appetizers" are generally understood to mean the light food before a meal (though in the context of a banquet where the snacks in OP's picture do actually precede a meal, I suppose "appetizers" *would* be appropriate)

Comment: "Hors d'oeuvre" is a French term pronounced "or DURVE", more or less

Answer (score 16):

The term **[canapé](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canap%C3%A9)** is often used.

Technically, a canapé is just one kind of **hors d'oeuvre** – specifically, the kind with a small piece of bread or toast, or something similar, as a base – but the term has, in the UK at least, come to be used for all such foods.

Comment: It is particularly common in England to refer to any small pre-meal food such as this as a "canapé". I seldom hear the term "hors d'oeuvres".

Comment: @AlastairMaw The situation is the reverse in the US, in my experience. I'd never heard of canapé till five minutes ago.

Comment: @CarSmack Yeah, but then you guys call main courses entrées and are therefore deeply confused about this stuff. ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Such food is often referred to as **hors d'oeuvres.** Literally, "outside of the main work."

Comment: Because *hors d'oeuvres* is a French phrase, the pronunciation of the phrase does not follow English's normal phonetic rules.  The [pronunciation](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/hors-d-oeuvre) is close to "or derves", and more-or-less rhymes with "for serves".